# JavaScript client for Spring WS

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-ws

I have spring soap web service that works well. But my js client

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
if(req.readyState == 4){....}
req.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/CurrencyService', true);
req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
req.send(msg);
```

throws

```
405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:8080/CurrencyService
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know anything about Spring WS, but apaprently whatever you have defined to handle /CurrencyService doesn't accept a POST.  Skimming the [docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html) I'd say your WebServiceMessageReceiverHttpHandler is missing or misconfigured.